# Conky is crazy!

Tags: 12.04, gnome, conky

I have just installed conky on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS but it appears... in the terminal ( and only in it ):

```
$ conky

Uptime: 0h 3m 35s
Frequency (in MHz): 800
Frequency (in GHz): 0.80
RAM Usage: 740MiB/3.76GiB - 19% ##________
Swap Usage: 0B/3.72GiB - 0% __________
CPU Usage: 6% #_________
Processes: 146  Running: 1
File systems:
 / 14.1GiB/91.7GiB ##________
Networking:
Up: 0B  - Down: 0B
Name              PID   CPU%   MEM%
 conky             2445   0.00   0.03
 bash              2390   0.00   0.12
 gnome-pty-helpe   2389   0.00   0.02
 gnome-terminal    2383   0.00   0.52
```

I have tryed other conkyrc files to customize it but I get somethings like this:

```
$ conky -C /home/ubu/Scrivania/conky_grey/conkyrc_grey 
# Conky, a system monitor, based on torsmo
#
# Any original torsmo code is licensed under the BSD license
#
# All code written since the fork of torsmo is licensed under the GPL
#
# Please see COPYING for details
#
# Copyright (c) 2004, Hannu Saransaari and Lauri Hakkarainen
# Copyright (c) 2005-2010 Brenden Matthews, Philip Kovacs, et. al. (see AUTHORS)
# All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#

background no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2
no_buffers yes
out_to_stderr no
update_interval 1.0
uppercase no
use_spacer none

TEXT
${scroll 16 $nodename - $sysname $kernel on $machine | }
Uptime: $uptime
Frequency (in MHz): $freq
Frequency (in GHz): $freq_g
RAM Usage: $mem/$memmax - $memperc% ${membar 4}
Swap Usage: $swap/$swapmax - $swapperc% ${swapbar 4}
CPU Usage: $cpu% ${cpubar 4}
Processes: $processes  Running: $running_processes
File systems:
 / ${fs_used /}/${fs_size /} ${fs_bar 6 /}
Networking:
Up: ${upspeed eth0}  - Down: ${downspeed eth0}
Name              PID   CPU%   MEM%
 ${top name 1} ${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
 ${top name 2} ${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
 ${top name 3} ${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
 ${top name 4} ${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
```

Comment: Try setting the "own_window_type" variable to *normal*. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, try this conkyrc file. This one works for me. Does it work for you as well? If it does, perhaps you can try to adapt it to your own needs.

http://pastebin.com/ijZijExK

Comment: I have just tryed your conkyrc file, but also in this case it appears only in the terminal :(

Comment: Darn. This sure is a weird error. How did you install conky? apt-get?

Comment: I have installed it with Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: This feels like a shot in the dark, but perhaps you should try removing it thru the software center, then installing it through apt-get on the command line (apt-get install conky). There's a few packages: $ apt-cache search conky
conky - highly configurable system monitor (transitional package)
conky-all - highly configurable system monitor (all features enabled)
conky-cli - highly configurable system monitor (basic version)
conky-std - highly configurable system monitor (default version)
Try the conky-all one first.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it and all config files by typing this command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove package name
```

and install back using this command

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all
```

After that, run back your conky.